# Corda Nodes with more than one public key

Tags: blockchain, corda, public-key

I am trying to do a scenario which uses the composite keys . I want to have more than public keys so that i can sign a txn with either of the keys.

And the reference for the scenario is here :
https://docs.corda.net/api/kotlin/corda/net.corda.core.crypto/-composite-key/index.html

From my understanding , deployNodes task generate node with single public key.
please correct me if i am going out of the track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Corda 3.2, each node only has a single well-known keypair (i.e. a keypair that is linked to their identity in their certificate).

However, nodes can also generate as many confidential identity keypairs (i.e. keypairs they use when they want to remain confidential in a transaction) as they like. You generate these using:

```
val partyAndCertificate = serviceHub.keyManagementService.freshKeyAndCert(
    ourIdentityAndCert, false)

val publicKey = partyAndCertificate.owningKey
```

Please note that the confidential identities API remains unstabilised as of Corda 3.2, as documented [here](https://docs.corda.net/corda-api.html#internal-apis-and-stability-guarantees).

Comment: Thanks for the input